# changing collection select to autocomplete association in rails 4 for create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, select, activerecord, autocomplete

I have a rails app with task model, user model and profile model. User has_many tasks and user has_one profile. Assigner(user) can choose one executor(user) in the new task form. In the user model there is the email address attr that is used to find the task executor w/ collection select in the current new task form.

In the profile model there is first_name, last_name and company name. I wanna use these attributes to find the new task executor w/ autocomplete association. Something like "John Smith Company Inc" would pop up when the user starts typing either the names or the company. I've followed the related railscasts episode but I couldn't pull it off, as here are multiple models and attributes are involved.

I tried different approaches but none of those worked. I can't even save the new task so that was the first I would like to fix.

**UPDATE**: -------------------------

It's working at the moment w/ the code below UPDATE, but it's not the most efficient.
1. For example if I type (first_name and last_name) OR (first_name and company) into the text area then jquery-ui will return nothing with the LIKE query. So if I hit Peter or Smith then Peter Smith will pop-up, but if I hit Peter Smith then it won't find Peter Smith.
2. When I'm trying to save the task the after choosing sby I encounter some problems regarding finding the certain executor based on the rendered json. For example most company name contains space like Dream Inc. To avoid this problem I'm using this to find the executor: ---where("first_name LIKE ? AND last_name LIKE ?", name.split(' ')[0].camelize, name.split(' ')[1].camelize)--- but it's not gonna create the task if there is a space either in the first_name or last_name.

How can I optimize my code?

---

OLD CODE:

task.rb

```
belongs_to :assigner, class_name: "User"
belongs_to :executor, class_name: "User"
```

user.rb

```
has_many :assigned_tasks, class_name: "Task", foreign_key: "assigner_id", dependent: :destroy
has_many :executed_tasks, class_name: "Task", foreign_key: "executor_id", dependent: :destroy
```

old task.new.html.erb:

```
<div class="field form-group">
  <%= f.label :executor_id %>
  <%= f.collection_select(:executor_id, User.all, :id, :email, class: "form-control") %>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**

new task.new.html.erb:

```
<div class="field form-group">
  <%= f.label :task_name_company %>
  <%= f.text_field :task_name_company, class: "form-control" %>
</div>
```

task.rb (virtual attr w/ getter and setter method)

```
def task_name_company
  [executor.try(:profile).try(:first_name), executor.try(:profile).try(:last_name), executor.try(:profile).try(:company)].join(' ')
end

def task_name_company=(name)
  self.executor = User.joins(:profile).where("first_name LIKE ? AND last_name LIKE ?", name.split(' ')[0].camelize, name.split(' ')[1].camelize).first
end
```

tasknamecompanies_controller.rb (for jQuery-UI)

```
class TasknamecompaniesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @executors = User.joins(:profile).where("first_name LIKE ? OR last_name LIKE ? OR company LIKE ?", "%#{params[:term].camelize}%", "%#{params[:term].camelize}%", "%#{params[:term].camelize}%").all
    render json: @executors.pluck(:first_name, :last_name, :company).map{|e| e.join(' ')}
  end
end
```

Comment: Which railscast did you follow? Your code doesn't seem to have functionality for autocomplete—just for searching.

Comment: Hey Bryan, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M7yhPlIehFA. Yeah autocompletion was not there yet since I couldn't create the task. Now task creation is working w/ the code above, but I don't see how I could put there the autcomplete function for my task_name_company method.

Comment: I'll just put it out there, that railscast is for Rails 3. You're probably using Rails 4 and you should. So here's a railscast tutorial for autocomplete in Rails 4: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iMz8HmrQ350

Comment: Thanks Bryan, I am checking it out and will let you know how it worked out.

Comment: Bryan, this railscast seems to be Rails 3 as well. I started w/ rails 4, so I don't recognize the differences.

Comment: Bryan, could you take a look at the updated code and question? Thx